# How to initialize a leaflet map using formly custom template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, angular-formly

I'm using Angular-Formly to create a form where you input a address and it returns a map from this local. I'm created a custom template with the following:

`<script type="text/ng-template" id="leaflet-map-template.html">
  <div id="[options.key]"></div>
</script>`

And set the type at `angular.module` with other modules:

```
var app = angular.module('formlyExample', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'formly',
    'formlyBootstrap',
    'ui.bootstrap'
  ], function config(formlyConfigProvider) {
    // set custom template here
    formlyConfigProvider.setType({
      name: 'leaflet-map',
      templateUrl: 'leaflet-map-template.html'
    });
  });
```

But at the field I don't know how to initialize the leaflet-map. This is a part of my fields array:

```
vm.formFields = [
//other fields come here
//leaflet map template
{
  key: 'mymap',
  type: 'leaflet-map',
  templateOptions: {
  label: 'Leaflet Map'
  },
  controller: /* @ngInject */ function($scope) {
    var initialCoordinates = [-23.0895164, -47.2187371];
    // initialize map with initial coordinates
    var map = L.map($scope.options.key, {
      center: initialCoordinates,
      zoom: 14,
      zoomControl: false
    });
  }
}];
```

--EDIT--
The error it gives me is: `Map container not found`, because it can't find the `div`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work because the controller will get called at a point where there's no element with the proper ID in the DOM, because Formly hasn't applied the template yet.

So... how to fix it? First off, you should use a `link` function instead of a `controller`, because link functions are the default place to do DOM manipulations in Angular.

Also, to keep you from having to provide a link function every time you instantiate a map field, put the link function in the type definition, not in the field definition.

Finally, link functions receive the enclosing element as the second argument, so all you have to do to get the `div` is just get the first child of the enclosing element.

The code will look like this:

```
formlyConfigProvider.setType({
  name: 'leafletmap',
  templateUrl: 'leaflet-map-template.html',
  link: function(scope, el) {
    // initialize map with initial coordinates
    var initialCoordinates = [-23.0895164, -47.2187371];
    // get first child of the enclosing element - the <div>!
    var mapDiv = el.children()[0];
    var map = L.map(mapDiv, {
      center: initialCoordinates,
      zoom: 14,
      zoomControl: false
    });
  }
});
```

Oh, two things I forgot to tell you:

First, if you wanted to pass the field key as an ID, you should have done just like a regular angular template, with the double curly braces:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="leaflet-map-template.html">
  <div id="{{options.key}}"></div>
</script>
```

Finally, you don't need to put an ID in that `div`, because we're using the first child of the enclosing field element to select it. :)

To wrap it up, I put a minimal working example up on codepen, take a look:
https://codepen.io/sigriston/pen/OXxPPb